# how can I call PUT after GET in Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Requesting GET then PUT in Postman works as expected, although I don't see how to programmatically do this in node.

example:

Request GET localhost:3000/orders/Asia
returns 50 stock

Request PUT localhost:3000/orders/Asia/40
returns 10

```
app.get('/orders/:coffeeid', function(req, res) { 
  db.collection('coffees').find({'name': req.params.coffeeid}).toArray((err, result) => { 
    if (err) return res.send(500, err)
    var data = {
        "orders": {
            "name": result.coffeeid,
            "stock": result.stock
        }
    };
    res.json(result);
})
})

app.put('/orders/:coffeeid/:quantity', function(req, res) {

  db.collection('coffees').find({'name': req.params.coffeeid}).toArray((err, result) => { 
    if (err) return res.send(500, err)
    orders = {
        "name": req.params.name,
        "quantity": req.params.quantity
    };

console.log(result[0].stock, orders.quantity, orders.quantity <= result[0].stock) // resolvido
console.log(orders.quantity)

if (Number(orders.quantity) <= Number(result[0].stock) ) {

  result[0].stock = result[0].stock - orders.quantity
  db.collection('coffees').updateOne({'name': req.params.coffeeid}, result[0], function(err, result) {
    console.log('Order dispached. Thank you');
    res.json(result);
    res.render('orders.ejs', {orders: result, success: false})
  });
}
else {
  console.log('There isnt enough in stock. Will dispach ASAP');
  res.json({error: true});
}

  })
})
```

How can I programmatically call update after "getting" the stock value from get?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're trying to call the method in the `PUT` request after running the `GET` request?

Comment: @MatthewWeeks Yes. In this case, should print 'Order dispatched. Thank you'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the answer will be is instead of declaring anonymous function for `PUT` request, you can do this 
`

```
const whatEverYouWant =function(req, res) {

  db.collection('coffees').find({'name': req.params.coffeeid}).toArray((err, result) => { 
    if (err) return res.send(500, err)
    orders = {
        "name": req.params.name,
        "quantity": req.params.quantity
    };

console.log(result[0].stock, orders.quantity, orders.quantity <= result[0].stock) // resolvido
console.log(orders.quantity)

if (Number(orders.quantity) <= Number(result[0].stock) ) {

  result[0].stock = result[0].stock - orders.quantity
  db.collection('coffees').updateOne({'name': req.params.coffeeid}, result[0], function(err, result) {
    console.log('Order dispached. Thank you');
    res.json(result);
    res.render('orders.ejs', {orders: result, success: false})
  });
}
else {
  console.log('There isnt enough in stock. Will dispach ASAP');
  res.json({error: true});
}

  })
}
app.get('/orders/:coffeeid', function(req, res) { 
  db.collection('coffees').find({'name': req.params.coffeeid}).toArray((err, result) => { 
    if (err) return res.send(500, err)
    var data = {
        "orders": {
            "name": result.coffeeid,
            "stock": result.stock
        }
    };
          yourPutRequest(req,res) //
    res.json(result);
})
})

app.put('/orders/:coffeeid/:quantity',whatEverYouWant)
```

`[image: postman PUT]

Comment: Both console.log return undefined

Comment: what does console.log(result) print for u ?

Comment: undefined too.. But what you are suggesting, I can't call PUT to update my order0 with /coffeeid/quantity. It wont work

Comment: what is the value of this req.params.coffeeid? 
why nout ?
what you can do is when calling yourPutRequest(req,res) you need to pass your parms  `yourPutRequest({...req,params:{coffeeid:1,quantity:1}},res)`

Comment: orders.quantity is undefined, because we are not passing the argument variable into the PUT function. And req.params.coffeeid is also undefined

Comment: yes as I mentioned  here`yourPutRequest({...req,params:{coffeeid:1,quantity:1}},res) `this how you define them